# Check empty EditText inside OnTextChanged

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie android developer.. Now, I want to check whether all my EditTexts are empty or not.. Below is my approach:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    Log.d("qwe", String.valueOf(inputSearchNama.getText()));
    if(String.valueOf(inputSearchNama.getText()).isEmpty() || String.valueOf(inputSearchJenis.getText()).isEmpty()  || String.valueOf(inputSearchMerk.getText()).isEmpty()) {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        try {
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
        db.close();
        List<PriceList> getPrice = db.getSearchedPriceList(cs, String.valueOf(inputSearchMerk.getText()), String.valueOf(inputSearchJenis.getText()));
        ListAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getPrice);
        theListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I try to debug my EditText, it shows `qwe﹕ [ 01-27 20:15:03.783   214:0x103 I/InputReader ]` instead of empty string.. Any Idea ?

Comment: What is the exact problem youre facing?

Comment: I can't detect empty EditText..

Comment: See my answer. String.valueOf is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try Below code**

```
private TextWatcher watcher;
......................................
inputSearchNama.addTextChangedListener(watcher);    //register watcher to edittext
inputSearchJenis.addTextChangedListener(watcher);   //register watcher to edittext
inputSearchMerk.addTextChangedListener(watcher);    //register watcher to edittext
watcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(inputSearchNama.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                //write your code here
            }
             if(inputSearchJenis.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                //write your code here
            }
            if(inputSearchMerk.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                //write your code here
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    };
```

Comment: What will your `if statement` do? Is it the same as three of them are empty ?

Comment: For every edittext those three callback will execute. Just checking whether the editext data, on which edittext user entering tetxt empty or not

Comment: Not what I wanted, my important issue is that I could check whether the EditText is empty..

Comment: Ok, thats fine, when you want to check? You need to check every time?

Comment: Yup, whenever the user edit the EditText.. See what I did in my current approach, 1 last step is to check if it's empty..

Comment: @user26409021 Answer updated, Please check it. if you want three editext condition in one if condition, you can edit answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69956/discussion-between-sandeep-maram-and-user26409021).

Answer (score 7):

You may use something like below where edtContent is an `EditText`. If you have multiple `EditText's` define the `TextWatcher` elsewhere and pass the same instance to all of the `EditText` instances as a `TextChangedListener` via the `addTextChangedListener` method.

```
edtContent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim())) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem.

getText() does not return a string. It returns an Editable object.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html

So, when you convert the Editable to a string in your log statement using String.valueOf(), you are actually printing info from the Editable, not getting the string value it holds.

Try:

```
log.d("qwe", inputSearchNama.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Still the same behaviour, `Log.d("test",inputSearchNama.getText().toString())` returns  `test﹕ [ 01-31 11:33:22.289   103:0xc0 V/AudioPolicyManagerBase ]`

Comment: Are you sure you rebuilt your application correctly? You should not be getting the same behavior.